# Why repeat bracha on Hallel if the shaliach has said it and you have answered amen

Tags: tefilla, blessing

On Rosh Hodesh, before hallel, the shaliach says the bracha on hallel and the kahal answers amen and then repeats the bracha. Why is this bracha treated differently than most others.  Typically, if someone else says a bracha and you say amen you are covered by their bracha.*  (Yes, the person leading the davening can have the intent not to cover you, and you can have the intent not to be covered, but that is an unusual approach.)  Why do we take this unusual approach to the bracha before Hallel?  (All the most so because Hallel is only rabbinic in nature.)

*For example, on Rosh Hashanna the person blowing shofar says the bracha :hear shofar" and we say amen and do not repeat the bracha.

Comment: Is there an example of someone saying a bracha during savening and you say amen where you're covered by their bracha?

Comment: Who's we? I used the Shatz's blessing this morning.

Comment: @robev the blessings surrounded Shema. Really any blessing except the Shmone Esrei is a fine example.

Comment: @DoubleAA of course it's possible; I'm just curious if the OP used the shatz for all of davening and therefore is shocked by his not using the shatz for hallel, or never does and therefore shouldn't really be focusing on hallel.

Comment: @robev. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: Is shofar really comparable? There only one person usually does the blowing, so they would make the bracha for others. Here everyone is saying hallel themself.

Comment: @robev. I think it is comparable.  The bracha says to hear, not to blow.

Comment: @robev It's comparable in that in principle, everyone could be Yotzei with the blessing on Hallel, or everyone could say their own blessing for Shofar, Megillah, etc.

Comment: Is Shofar typical and Hallel atypical? Hallel happens way more often. (Of course there's also the issue that you seem to be assuming whatever practice you've seen is universal or ideal or intentional, which is just silly. Try not asserting things without any basis.)

Comment: I'm not sure about shofar as an example - you're right about the wording of the bracha, but halachically the blower is motzi the listeners as well, so robev may have a point

Comment: @Jay Halakhically it's 100% fine for me to say the blessing just before someone else blows shofar for me. It doesn't matter that I'm not blowing because I'm hearing.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15703/501 could be merged with this. But it's not a real dup.

Comment: I'm surmising that because the wording in the bracha for Hallel is *Likro* - to read - there may be a requirement that every person must read it for himself. BTW, we have a similar situation for *Sefirat Ha'omer*, I believe. Assuming that one is still eligible to say the bracha, he answers "Amen" to the chazzan / rav's bracha, but still makes the bracha himself. Here, it's clear that the mitzvah is that each person must count, himself. I THINK the same rules apply to Lulav, and logically, it should apply to succah as well. Another person cannot sit for you.

Comment: Dirshu Mishna Berurah brings that the chazon ish would not wait for the end of the Shatz's bracha, and would start saying his personal bracha right away.